# Configuring homebrew for multiple users on MacOs

Tags: macos, homebrew

## UPDATES

`brew --prefix` returns:

> /usr/local

## CONTEXT

A MacOs Mojave desktop is:

1. initially configured with brew
2. a new user is added

A new group, `brew`, is added per [instructions](https://medium.com/@energee/install-brew-for-multiple-users-65af2444df5c#) and user 2 was added to the `brew` group:

Change group of installation directory to “brew”:

```
sudo chgrp -R brew $(brew --prefix)/*
```

“brew” group given write access:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w $(brew --prefix)/*
```

The goal is to enable the `brew` command for any user.

## ERRORS

`brew update` returns

```
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/error.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/explicit_namespace.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/gem_inflector.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/inflector.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/real_mod_name.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/registry.rb': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/version.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/error.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/explicit_namespace.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/gem_inflector.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/inflector.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/real_mod_name.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/registry.rb': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.1/lib/zeitwerk/version.rb': Permission denied
Already up-to-date.
```

## QUESTIONS

The goal is to enable the `brew` command for user 2. The directory /Library/Homebrew does not exist.

1. What is causing `brew update` warning & error messages?
2. What remedies are available?

Comment: Please edit question with output of `brew --prefix`.

Comment: @dirkt `brew --prefix` returns  /usr/local

Comment: @dirkt. What does the out reveal?  I would like to understand the diagnostic

Comment: `brew update` should be updating the state inside the directory subtree described by the prefix, e.g. `/usr/local`. That's what it does on my machine, On your machine, it tries to touch `/Library/Homebrew/` for some reason, which doesn't even exist on my machine, but I have no idea why that happens on your machine, or how to fix it. If the prefix would have pointed to `/Library/Homebrew`, then this would be a potential issue. But it doesn't.

Comment: I have the exact same problem @gatorback Did you manage to fix it? I believe I followed the same instruction in the past to make a multi-user brew instance, but Apple changed some system settings, and now it's broken. Thanks in advance for the reply!

Comment: The machine was given to a relative and was not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598733/configuring-homebrew-for-multiple-users-on-macos/690108#comment1118388_598733)

> On your machine, it tries to touch /Library/Homebrew/ for some reason

No, the location is actually

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/
```

---

> 1. What is causing brew update warning & error messages?
> 2. What remedies are available?

Adding group write permissions for multiuser config fixes this:-

```
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/
```

Comment: You emphatically say "No", but the OP's question *quite clearly* shows that, on the OP's machine, `/Library/Homebrew` is being touched... this may not be the usual path, and may not match *your* Homebrew installation, but you can't deny that the OP's setup is using (or trying to use) `/Librayr/Homebrew/`, for whatever reason - the output of `brew update` is proof.